# Changing model depending on user in Generic View give error when using __init__ method

Tags: django-views, initialization, init, django-generic-views

I'm trying to change the model used by a generic Django view (UpdateView) depending on the user.
But when I try to get the user with request.user I get an attribute error:

```
  'RegistroUpdate' object has no attribute 'request'
```

When I use request in def get_object, it works only if I don't use def **init** but, as soon as I try to use it I get the error.

I don't know how can I use request here. Any help will be welcome.

This is the code where I have the mistake:

```
  class RegistroUpdate(UpdateView):
      model=None
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(**kwargs)
          act_as=self.request.session.get('act_as','enfermero')
          if act_as=='enfermero':
              self.model=Registro_enfermeria
              self.form_class= EnfermeriaForm
    
          else:
              self.model=Resto_personal
              self.form_class=RestopersonalForm

    def get_object(self):
        act_as=self.request.session.get('act_as','enfermero')
        if act_as=='enfermero':
           #get object
           
       else:
            # get other object
```

How can I use request when using def **init**?
thanks

Comment: at the moment of `__init__`, there is no `request` *yet*, that is set by the `setup()` method that is called later in the process.

Comment: I would also advise *not* to use session variables for this, since these have some state-like behavior. Furthermore it makes behavior less predictable: what if for example `act_as` is `'foo'`?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things are more simple than they look like.
Thanks to the comments of Willem, I decided not to use **init** method and kept searching other ways to do it.
This is the solution I founded. At the moment it seems to work:

```
  class RegistroUpdate(UpdateView):
  model=None
  template_name=my_template.html
      

def get_object(self):
    
    act_as=self.request.session.get('act_as','enfermero')
      if act_as=='enfermero':
          self.model=Registro_enfermeria
          self.form_class= EnfermeriaForm
          #get object

      else:
          self.model=Resto_personal
          self.form_class=RestopersonalForm
          #get other object
```

So, **init** method was not needed here. Much more simple!